# How to duplicate Rust Stream

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a program similar to the following:

```
struct MyEvent { /* some fields */ }
struct MyStruct { /* some fields */ }
struct MyStreamer { /* holds some state */ }

impl MyStreamer {
    pub fn stream_objects<'a, 'b: 'a>(
        &'a self,
        event_stream: Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = MyEvent> + Send + 'b>>,
    ) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Arc<MyStruct>> + Send + 'a>> { /* implementation */ }
}
```

The goal is to process events and build a stream of `MyStruct`. I then have two consumers for the stream of `MyStruct` and I'm struggling to duplicate it.

I'm trying to write the following function (also see my attempted implementation):

```
pub fn duplicate_stream<'a, 'b: 'a>(
    &'a self,
    struct_stream: Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Arc<MyStruct>> + Send + 'b>>,
) -> (
   Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Arc<MyStruct>> + Send + 'b>>,
   Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Arc<MyStruct>> + Send + 'b>>
) {
        let (s1, r1) = mpsc::unbounded::<Arc<MyStruct>>();
        let (s2, r2) = mpsc::unbounded::<Arc<MyStruct>>();

        let s = s1.fanout(s2);

        let _handle = tokio::spawn(async move { struct_stream.map(Ok).forward(s).await });

        (r1.boxed(), r2.boxed())
}
```

At this point, I'm told the following:

```
    |
155 |         struct_stream: Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Arc<MyStruct>> + Send + 'b>>,
    |                               ----------------------------------------------- this data with lifetime `'b`...
...
165 |         let _handle = tokio::spawn(async move { struct_stream.map(Ok).forward(s).await });
    |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...is captured here...
    |
note: ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
   --> *file name here*
    |
165 |         let _handle = tokio::spawn(async move { struct_stream.map(Ok).forward(s).await });
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I can remove the lifetimes, but then `static` will be inferred and I get errors in the callers.

I'm curious to understand what the best way is to clone all the elements of a stream and obtain two identical streams. Using `tokio::spawn` and `mpsc` channels seems to require changing a lot of lifetimes to `static`.

Comment: I think "duplicate" is not the right term for what you are looking for. Perhaps "split".

Comment: @Elazar I was thinking about using "split", but felt that it implies that I want some elements of the stream to go to stream 1 and some to stream 2.

Comment: @RaduSzasz Two identical streams as in `a.next()` and `b.next()` will be the same, or `a` and `b` both share an underlying stream and calling `.next()` on one will advance both (similar to `Iterator::by_ref`)?

Comment: @Aplet123 `a.next()` and `b.next()` should return the same. Assume `struct_stream = stream::iter!(vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter())` and `let (s1, s2) = duplicate_stream(struct_stream)`. Then `s1.next()` returns `1`. Ditto, `s2.next()` returns `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Compiler is correct and you probably should think about the lifetimes because the fanout is ok.

`tokio::spawn` requires `'static` and you have `'b` lifetime specified for your `struct_stream`. Maybe wrap the `struct_stream` in an `Arc/Rc`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My question is concerned strictly with "I have one stream and I want to have two streams. How do I do that?" Feel free to suggest a better phrasing to make it clear.

I generally include the things I already tried in my question so that it's obvious that I didn't just post on StackOverflow immediately as I ran into the issue and folks know the path I've been on so far. I don't expect the answers I receive to fix lifetimes (unless that's the best way to go about the question).

Comment: @RaduSzasz and I think I responded in the latter part of my comment. I think (I'm not the best rustacean but had most of it using tokio) that what you did (use fanout) is correct approach that doesn't work because you use lifetimes incorrectly and I suggested that one way of approaching lifetime mismatch would be to wrap `struct_stream` with a ref count. Your approach doesn't work because it's wrong but because the code isn't correct.